# Queuing data to redis with php-resque is slow

Tags: php, apachebench, redis-server, php-resque

I'm using [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) for queuing my jobs. And I'm doing apache ab tool to benchmark my performance.

`php-resque` does good job, but it's slow as every time my it connects to redis which impacts performance (without connection it handles `~130 Requests/sec` and with `Resque::enqueue` it's `~30 requests/sec`).

So I was thinking to pass data to another file through `exec` which will connect redis and queus job in the background, but found that `exec` is way much slow.

What is next ? How can I make it handle redis queuing faster.

Note: I'm using this command to test performance.

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 "http://localhost/index.php"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.

#### Here are the steps:

After digging `php-resque` I found that it's using [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) which makes it slow.

Then I installed `php-redis` on my ubuntu machine. By executing following command.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-redis
```

Then restarted apache server by :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And then connected with redis by following lines of code.

```
<?php 
$redis = new Redis();
$result = $redis->connect('127.0.0.1'); 
$id = md5(uniqid('', true));
$redis->set("resque:job:$id",$args);
$redis->close();
unset($redis);
```

After this code testing with gave better performance `(~70 requests/second)` which is doubled than before.

*Note: here `pconnect` stands for persistent connection, which is faster than `connect`.*

Hope this helps someone.